# Displaying posts in custom formation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I would like to output posts in order provided by this image (every 3 posts)

[image: posts formation that is needed]

here is my blade code:

```html
<section class="blog_area p_120">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <div class="blog_left_sidebar">
                    @foreach ($raksti as $raksts)
                    <article class="blog_style1">
                        <div class="blog_img">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="{{$raksts->image}}" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="blog_text">
                            <div class="blog_text_inner">
                                <div class="cat">
                                    <a class="cat_btn" href="#">{{$raksts->kato->title}}</a>
                                    <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{$raksts->created_at}}
                                    <i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 05
                                </div>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <h4>{{$raksts->title}}</h4>
                                </a>
                                <p>{{$raksts->short_desc}}</p>
                                <a class="blog_btn" href="#">Lasīt vairāk</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

For those small blocks the "article" tag have class ="blog_style1 small"

I guess that there need to work with a "for" loop, so can anyone help me to achieve this task and explain a little how that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try next code

```
@foreach ($raksti as $key => $raksts)
 //
 @if($key % 3 == 1)
 // set here style css width 100 %

 @else
 // set here style css width 50 %
 @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: I made it with  if($key % 3 == 0) and after if and else statements modify html code. Thanks for way where to look :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look, you need to tell your code that one image of three has to be wide.
So that you can use modulo:

```
@foreach ($raksti as $key => $value)
    @if($key % 3 = 0)
       // set width 100%
    @else
       // set width 50%
    @endif
@endforeach
```

That makes every third element as 100% wide.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has loop variables:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#the-loop-variable

You can use `$loop->index` inside yor foreach and check whether your article must have class `small`

```php
<article class="blog_style1 @if($loop->index % 3 !== 0) small @endif">
```

Or you can simply use CSS `nth-child`

https://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Answer (score 0):

Give class `small` each third element

```html
<section class="blog_area p_120">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <div class="blog_left_sidebar">
                    @foreach ($raksti as $key => $raksts)
                    <article class="blog_style1 {{ ($key % 3 != 0) ? 'small' : ''  }}">
                        <div class="blog_img">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="{{$raksts->image}}" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="blog_text">
                            <div class="blog_text_inner">
                                <div class="cat">
                                    <a class="cat_btn" href="#">{{$raksts->kato->title}}</a>
                                    <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{$raksts->created_at}}
                                    <i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 05
                                </div>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <h4>{{$raksts->title}}</h4>
                                </a>
                                <p>{{$raksts->short_desc}}</p>
                                <a class="blog_btn" href="#">Lasīt vairāk</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

no need to do this in the backend. Use the nth-child functionality of CSS:

```
.blog_style1{
    width: 50%;
}
.blog_style1:nth-child(4n){
    width: 100%;
}
```